# JQuery or JavaScript - get name of btn clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I have a quiz like slideshow that dynamically generates the questions and the list of answer options.

The answer options are of input type button and are generated dynamically from a table. The button name is also dynamically generated. The number of answer options is dymamic.

When a user clicks on an answer option I need to capture the name of the button.

I have tested out several interations of my code but am not successfully capturing the button clicked. Any input, insight is greately appreicated. Code is below. Just a quick callout - the HTML works without issue. I am using AMPSCRIPT for a Salesforce Makreting Cloud pages.

```js
function btnAnswer(){
 var btnClicked = $('.slide :button[clicked]');
 var btnValue = $(btnClicked).val();
 var btnName = $(btnClicked).attr("name");
 var btnQuestion = btnName.substring(0, btnName.indexOf('A'));
 btnQuestion = btnQuestion.substring(btnQuestion.indexOf('Q') + 1);
 var btnAnswer = btnName.substring(btnName.indexOf('A') + 1);
 updateScore(btnQuestion, btnAnswer);
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="slide">
           <p class="question-p">%%=TreatAsContent(FIELD(ROW(@quizData,@qNum),'QuestionBackground'))=%%</p>
           <h3 class="question-h3">%%=TreatAsContent(FIELD(ROW(@quizData,@qNum),'Question'))=%%</h3>
           <div id="" class="question">
            %%[
            SET @answerOptions = BuildRowsetFromString(FIELD(ROW(@quizData,@qNum),'QuestionAnswerOptions'),'|')
            SET @answerCount = RowCount(@answerOptions)
            FOR @aNum = 1 to @answerCount DO
            SET @answer = FIELD(ROW(@answerOptions,@aNum),1)
            ]%%
             <div id="answerOptions">
              <input value="%%=TreatAsContent(@answer)=%%" class="button-submit btnAnswer" name="Q%%=V(@qNum)=%%A%%=V(@aNum)=%%" type="button">
             </div>
            %%[
            NEXT @aNum
            ]%%
            <!-- BEGIN HIDE CRCT ANSWER FOR JS VALIDATION -->
            <input name="crctAnswer" value="%%=V(FIELD(ROW(@quizData,@qNum),'questionCrctAnswerValue'))=%%" type="hidden">
           </div>
           <!-- END HIDE CRCT ANSWER FOR JS VALIDATION -->
           <!-- HIDE/SHOW BASED ON SELECTION -->
           <div id="" class="answer">
            <div class="answer-title" style="display:none;"> <img class="icon" src="http://image.em.pge.com/lib/fe8c13727666037a72/m/6/general_cancel.png">
             <h4 class="answer-h4-incorrect" style="display:none;">You are incorrect.</h4> </div>
            <div class="answer-title" style="display:none;"> <img class="icon" src="http://image.em.pge.com/lib/fe8c13727666037a72/m/6/general_check.png">
             <h4 class="answer-h4-correct" style="display:none;">You are correct!</h4> </div>
            <div class="answer-explaination" style="display:none;">
             <p class="answer-explaination" style="display:none;"><strong>The correct answer.</strong>%%=TreatAsContent(FIELD(ROW(@quizData,@qNum),'QuestionCrctAnswerText'))=%%</p>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I believe in the click event `this` becomes the node of the button that was clicked. You can then get what you want out of the node.

Comment: It depends on if the binding is an inline binding or not.  I don't see in the OP how the binding is created.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you'd use Jquery like this:

```
$(".btnAnswer").click(function() {
    // jQuery way
    var btnValue = $(this).val();
    var btnName = $(this).attr("name");

    // Javascript way
    var btnValue = this.value;
    var btnName = this.name;

    var btnQuestion = btnName.substring(0, btnName.indexOf('A'));
    btnQuestion = btnQuestion.substring(btnQuestion.indexOf('Q') + 1);
    var btnAnswer = btnName.substring(btnName.indexOf('A') + 1);
    updateScore(btnQuestion, btnAnswer);
});
```

Comment: `this.name` and `this.value` work without creating two different jQuery objects.

Comment: I'm aware that it will work.  I'm pointing out an inefficiency that could be improved upon.

Comment: He asked how to get the clicked button in Jquery or Javascript. Now the example show both ways

Comment: And I'm pointing out that doing `$(this).val()` is performing two operations.  It creates a brand new jQuery operation, so it has to go through all the overhead associated with that, and then it calls the val() method which will return the value property.  When all that could be done without and just use direct property access.  There may be readers that believe they *must* wrap the element in a jQuery object to get the value or the name attribute.  It is important to inform them that this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the jQuery button click handler

```
$(".btnAnswer").click( function() {
    $(this).attr('name');
    // or
    this.name;
});
```

Comment: The `button` in this example is actually an `input`, not to confuse OP.